# Store Connection Parameters for SQLAlchemy securely

Tags: python, security, sqlalchemy

I'm writing an application in Python 2.7 + SQLAlchemy that will need to access hundreds of PostgreSQL databases, each on its own server.  To connect using SQLAlchemy, an engine is created by passing it a URL in this format:

```
postgresql://userid:password@hostname:5432/database
```

Since there are so many databases, storing them in a flat file is not that practical; storing in a yet separate PostgreSQL database would make it easier to track them.

The issue is **how** to store the parameters (particularly the password) **securely**. Storing hashed values would be more secure, but can't be reversed to be then passed to SQLAlchemy to create an engine for the target database.

What is a good, secure approach to storing all of those sets of database connection parameters?

Comment: "Secure" against what attacks?  Why do you think using a network accessible database is better than a file accessible only to the owning user on that host?

Comment: Not better per se.  But with hundreds or even thousands of connections, a plain file can become unwieldy ("not practical").

Comment: Would a sqlite database do what you need? (hint: yes)

Comment: Why would an SQLite database be a better solution than PostgreSQL?

Comment: Because it works as a single file, so you don't need to think about hardening a network attached database from prying eyes; suitable posix file permissions for the user that runs the only process that needs to access this list of connection parameters.

Comment: One more requirement: we need to construct a sign-up process where a customer would fill out a web form (including username and password to be used).  That means the web app must be able to save the data; and in turn the SQLite database would be exposed to the web.  What about instead encrypting passwords with something like blowfish?